# Regex to make self closing tag

Tags: jquery, html, regex, xhtml

Is there any regex to convert xhtml tags to self closing tags. for e.g

Convert from

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
```

Comment: regex `(<[^>]*)>` replacement string `$1/>`

Comment: The regex above worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var str = '<input type="text" id="textbox1">';
str = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf(">")).concat("/>");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Trying to make regex which will applicable for HTML selft closing tags. There is possibility that <input type="text" id="textbox1"> comes in <div><input type="text" id="textbox1"></div> in this case how can i use above answer

Comment: From <div><input type="text" id="textbox1"></div>  to <div><input type="text" id="textbox1"/></div>   or <input type="text" id="textbox1"> to <input type="text" id="textbox1"/>

Comment: `var str = $("div input").get(0).outerHTML; str = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf(">")).concat("/>"); $("div").html(str)` ? Though browser may strip closing `/`

Comment: What is application ?

Comment: Application is to make web page templates. which has to add controls on page drag around, set properties. and store data in json format means save HTML page in json format. I am using xhtml as a doc type and browser strips / from all self closing tag which i dont want to do. All tags should have to close tags so that i can save proper json format string

Comment: Tried piece at post ?

Comment: @Unknown if you want to use XHTML, then use the XHTML _file type_! Simply using another DOCTYPE declaration doesn't change a HTML file into XHTML. That is also the reason why your browser strips the closing slashes. So use a file extension of .xhtml, or sent the http header to change the MIME type in the web app.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no self-closing tags:

```js
const s = `<input type="text" id="textbox1">`
console.log(s.replace(/<([^>]*)>/g, '<$1/>'))
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of $1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```

If there can already be some self-closing tags:

```js
const s = `<input type="text" id="textbox1"> and <input type="text" id="textbox2"/>`
console.log(s.replace(/<([^>]*[^>\/\s])(?:\s*\/)?\s*>/g, '<$1/>'))
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>]*                    any character except: '>' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>\/\s]                 any character except: '>', '\/',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of $1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```